# How do I center the image in an ObjectListView column?

Tags: .net, winforms, objectlistview

I am using ObjectListView in a C# winforms project and want to show a small icon in one of the columns.

So far, the icon is showing just fine, but it isn't centered in the column, and I cannot find any documentation or code that pertains to image alignment within a column.

[Here are the instructions for displaying an image as the column contents](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-make-a-column-that-shows-just-an-image).

The code is virtually the same as the example given:

```
col_Important.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((ClassMyItem)x).IsImportant; };
col_Important.AspectToStringConverter = delegate(object x) { return String.Empty; };
col_Important.ImageGetter = delegate(object x)
    {
        return ((ClassMyItem)x).IsImportant? "star" : "none";
    };
```

Has anyone dealt with this issue and know of a way to center the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the process of manually drawing the subitem (using the `DrawSubItem` event), I inadvertently discovered that simply setting the ObjectListView property `OwnerDraw` to true actually centers the image.

Just to be clear, here is how the columns with only an image are drawn:

```
colName.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((MyClass)x).SomeProperty; };
colName.AspectToStringConverter = delegate(object x) { return String.Empty }; };
colName.ImageGetter =
    delegate(object x) { return ((MyClass)x).SomeProperty ? "icon" : "none"; };
```

The ObjectListView has its `SmallImageList` set to use the ImageList I created for it, which is where the `ImageGetter` method makes use of the image name ("icon" in this example).

By default, the images are drawn at the far left of the column, regardless of settings like text alignment, etc.

By setting `OwnerDraw` to true for the ObjectListView, the images are miraculously centered in the column with no other code addition whatsoever. This was unexpected behavior which probably merits more investigation. For now it works, so maybe this tip will help someone else as well.

Comment: I can't remove the [edit] comment because stackoverflow keeps insisting in editing at least 6 chars. Can someone please delete the block.

Comment: @Xan What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just added two semicolons and removed a brace, but got an error, that I had to edit at least 6 characters. So I thought I add some nonsense and delete that later, but the algorithm is too smart/annoying :-)

Comment: Just do the same edits then add &nbsp; to the end or something.

Comment: BTW, the new way would be `AspectToStringConverter = value => String.Empty;`

Answer (score 0):

how about making the list ownerdraw and center the image when drawing it (computing the x knowing the column bounds). Looking for an example right now..

here: [Center subitem Icon in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322408/center-subitem-icon-in-listview)

hope it helps.

Comment: I saw the linked answer and have definitely thought about it. I was hoping there might be a slightly easier way, given that I need to apply this fix in several places.

Comment: you may subclass the OLV to get that behaviour for all your lists.